# Pass container-local net to a smtp docker container (namshi/smtp)

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'd like to setup a smtp server via docker-compose, that is accessible just by the containers in the same net. I decided to use this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/namshi/smtp/

My current compose file looks like the following:

```
version: "2"

services:

  [...]

  smtp:
    image: namshi/smtp
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    networks:
      - internal
    environment:
      - RELAY_NETWORKS=??? (e.g. ":192.168.0.0/24") 
      - 'RELAY_DOMAINS=*'
      - MAILNAME=somedomain.org
    restart: unless-stopped

  [...]

networks:
  web:
    driver: bridge
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

The configuration of the image seems to require a setting for RELAY_NETWORKS, which is fine in order to prevent opening the relay to the public accidently.
The image uses exim4.

But as docker-compose builds the net, I would like to inject the net specifier somehow automatically. Is there a way to do that?